# I'm getting error while importing app from kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've installed Kivy some time ago, and since then I've tried many ways to run Kivy, but till today I'm not successful.

I am able to "import kivy" in python but while importing app module by "from kivy.app import app"
It shows error 'no module named app', while there is a folder in Kivy named "app".
The location of this folder is "D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy"

Here's my environment path which I have setup for Kivy:

> > > KIVY_DATA_DIR : D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy\data
> > >       KIVY_EXTS_DIR : D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy\tools\extensions
> > >       KIVY_HOME : D:.kivy; D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy
> > >       KIVY_MODULES_DIR : D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy; D:\utils\Kivy\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\kivy27\kivy\modules

Can anyone please help me....

Comment: Do you have a python27 directory as well with kivy under `Lib\site packages`? You might be searching in there rather than the directory you provided.

Comment: Try adding that dir to your sys.path within python before you import - as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path%20documentation) `sys.path.insert(0,"D:\utils\Kivy\")` or something like that

Comment: The location of "python27" directory is C:\Python27.. I've installed Kivy in D: directory with Python already installed in above mentioned directory.

Comment: Can you import kivy.app from a console session? Is your script called "kivy.py"?

Comment: I don't have any script naming "kivy.py"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use a old version of kivy? Use the latest version 1.9.1. follow the documentation

> Ensure you have the latest pip and wheel:
>
> `python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setup tools`
>
> . Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~90MB) if not needed, see Kivy’s dependencies):
>
> `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2
>   kivy.deps.glew \ kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url
>   https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/`
>
> Install kivy:
>
> `python -m pip install kivy`
>
> That’s it. You should now be able to import
>   kivy in python.

Comment: I have kivy installed but I'm not able to import any module like app, widget,etc.